# Eclipse indention for if statements without curly braces

Tags: php, eclipse, indentation

When using `if-statements` without curly braces, Eclipse don't indent them such as below:

```
if($i === $this->get_current_page())
$current_class = "class='current'";
else
$current_class = '';
```

But I do want to indent them like below:

```
if($i === $this->get_current_page())
   $current_class = "class='current'";
else
   $current_class = '';
```

I am using CTRL + Shift + F to indent the code.

By the way I am using Eclipse for PHP development.

Comment: Why on earth would you be excluding the curly braces. Don't do that! Seriously, lazy coding style makes other programmers hate you

Comment: Well I am not doing this for other developer but for myself. :)

Comment: @Braveyard in that case, people on the internets will hate you. ;) What's wrong with $current_class === $this->get_current_page( ) ? 'class="current"' : ''; by the way? No need for the whole extended if statement.

Comment: @Braveyard - Yeah but do you plan to write code for yourself for the rest of your life? Is it inconceivable that you will (in the future) be working with someone else? Don't mean to lecture you but I've worked on code written by 'that guy' and it looks like the code from the matrix - not fun

Comment: Give him a break, that's his coding standard that's it. Furthermore this notation is useful in views (when mixing PHP and HTML). I think this question deserves an answer, not a bypass.

Comment: I don't understand, it is just what I want. Thanks for your informative answers but what you recommend me is something I already know and I also want this way. If you don't know the answer that's okay but just give me a break. Thanks...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just add the braces, it's good coding practice!

Or use the ternary if:

```
$current_class = ($i === $this->get_current_page()) ? "class='current'" : "");
```

Comment: While this answer is syntactically correct, it doesn't answer his question: how to modify/control indentation in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I give my answer for Java, but I excpect that replacing "Java" by "PHP" should work as well:

Go to **Window** → **Preference**

Choose **Java** → **Code Style** → **Formatter**

Edit the format and look for whatever you need to change (indent or other things).

Save (export if you want to keep it)

Now `CTRL+SHIFT+F` will indent the code the way you wanted.

Comment: I didn't see such advanced feature for PHP.

Comment: That's okay then. Thanks for answering tho.